# How do you convert from a List to a primitive array of a different type

Tags: java

How do you convert from a List to an array of a different type (e.g. I would like to go from `List<Integer> to double[]`)

Comment: You might like to thing about how you handle null values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loops over the list and convert each element. Here's an example for `List<Integer>` to `double[]`.

```
public static double[] integersToDoubles(List<Integer> integers) {
    double[] ret = new double[integers.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = integers.get(i).doubleValue();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [toArray](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d)? You can find a simple example [here](http://www.codingdiary.com/developers/developers/diary/javaapi/java/util/SampleCode/ArrayListtoArray1ExampleCode.html)

Answer (score 2):

1) Iterate each element and convert it to `double` and add it to `double[]`

Comment: there's no need for to convert it into an array as in step 1. You can just iterate over the original list.

Comment: @dogbane oh yes. agreee , +1.

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate conversions required. One is from a List to an array. The second is for each of the elements from one type to another. The second may or may not be possible.

For the first see [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/343).

For the second there are well-defined transformations between numbers (ints, Doubles, etc.) Some are lossless, others lose precision.

Many types have a String representation and so you can write:

```
String s = foo.toString()
```

and perhaps:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(s);
```

But you have to understand these - there is no magic. If there is no String serialization you will get the machine address of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help full

```
List<Integer> List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List.add(new Integer(100));
    List.add(new Integer(200));
    List.add(new Integer(300));
    double[] db =new double[List.size()];
    System.out.println(List);
    for(int i=0;i<List.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(List.get(i).toString());
        db[i]=Double.parseDouble(List.get(i).toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A general approach - takes any type of collection and any `Number` input (even mixed types):

```
public static double[] toDoubles(Collection<? extends Number> numbers) {
    double[] result = new double[input.size()];
    int index = 0;

    for (Number number:numbers)
        result[index++] = number.doubleValue();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you can achieve this with only one line of code:

```
/**
 * Transform a list of objects into an array of primitives
 * 
 * @param listOfObject
 * @return
 */
public static double[] convertToPrimitives(List<Double> listOfObjects) {
    return listOfObjects.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
}

/**
 * Transform a list of objects into an array of primitives
 * 
 * @param listOfObject
 * @return
 */
public static double[] convertToPrimitives(List<Integer> listOfObjects) {
    return listOfObjects.stream().mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue).toArray();
}
```